# Difference in boiling points ( temperatures) of 2 elements

Tags: arithmetic

**In a chemistry class, students were learning about boiling point of various elements.Reuben has compiled a table that gives boiling points of each of various elements.
The lowest boiling point is of Element X: – 200 degrees Fahrenheit.
The highest boiling point is of Element Y: 550 degrees Fahrenheit
Find the difference between the lowest and highest boiling point.**

---

I know how to calculate the difference.
-200 – 550 = -750.
I am not sure if the answer is written as a negative or positive.
Will the answer be – 750 F or 750 F ?
Would greatly appreciate if you could explain what the correct answer is.

Comment: Even the part, "I know how to calculate..." is a duplicate of the older question!

Comment: My previous account has been deleted and I had not saved the replies. I am reposting the questions because I have no idea how to search for my previously posted questions. I hope that is not an issue, I am not trying to spam but genuinely asking for help!

Comment: I have flagged your comment for moderator attention, as a moderator may be able to help you. Posting a deliberate duplicate is definitely not the way to get what you want – contacting a moderator would have been a much better idea.

Comment: But, anyway, since you still had access to the wording of your original questions, why didn't you just type something of those questions into Google? Surely that would have found your questions for you.

Comment: Thanks . Hopefully a moderator will help me figure it out. I tried searching on the website for posts made me ( using my username) but nothing came up.Hence I reposted.